# delete the integer in timeindex

Tags: python, pandas

This is a part of a dataframe.as you can see, there are some Integer in the timeindex. It should not be a timestamp. So I want to just delete it.So how can we delete the records which has the integer as a timeindex?

```
        rent_time                    rent_price_per_square_meter
0      2016-11-28 09:01:58                     0.400000
1      2016-11-28 09:02:35                     0.400000
2      2016-11-28 09:02:43                     0.400000
3      2016-11-28 09:03:21                     0.400000
4      2016-11-28 09:03:21                     0.400000
5      2016-11-28 09:03:34                     0.400000
6      2016-11-28 09:03:34                     0.400000
7      2017-06-17 02:49:33                     0.933333
8      2017-03-19 01:30:03                     0.490196
9      2017-03-10 06:39:03                    11.111111
10     2017-03-09 14:40:03                    16.666667
11     908797                                 11.000000
12     2017-06-08 03:27:52                    22.000000
13     2017-06-30 03:03:11                    22.000000
14     2017-02-20 11:04:48                    12.000000
15     2017-03-05 13:53:39                     6.842105
16     2017-03-06 14:00:01                     6.842105
17     2017-03-15 02:38:54                    20.000000
18     2017-03-15 02:19:07                    13.043478
19     2017-02-24 15:10:00                    25.000000
20     2017-06-26 02:17:31                    13.043478
21     82368                                  11.111111
22     2017-06-30 07:53:55                     4.109589
23     2017-07-17 02:42:43                    20.000000
24     2017-06-30 07:38:00                     5.254237
25     2017-06-30 07:49:00                     4.920635
26     2017-06-30 05:26:26                     4.189189
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parameter `errors=coerce` for return `NaN`s for no `datetime` values and then add [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) for return all `datetime`s:

```
df1 = df[pd.to_datetime(df['rent_time'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
print (df1)
              rent_time  rent_price_per_square_meter
0   2016-11-28 09:01:58                     0.400000
1   2016-11-28 09:02:35                     0.400000
2   2016-11-28 09:02:43                     0.400000
3   2016-11-28 09:03:21                     0.400000
4   2016-11-28 09:03:21                     0.400000
5   2016-11-28 09:03:34                     0.400000
6   2016-11-28 09:03:34                     0.400000
7   2017-06-17 02:49:33                     0.933333
8   2017-03-19 01:30:03                     0.490196
9   2017-03-10 06:39:03                    11.111111
10  2017-03-09 14:40:03                    16.666667
12  2017-06-08 03:27:52                    22.000000
13  2017-06-30 03:03:11                    22.000000
14  2017-02-20 11:04:48                    12.000000
15  2017-03-05 13:53:39                     6.842105
16  2017-03-06 14:00:01                     6.842105
17  2017-03-15 02:38:54                    20.000000
18  2017-03-15 02:19:07                    13.043478
19  2017-02-24 15:10:00                    25.000000
20  2017-06-26 02:17:31                    13.043478
22  2017-06-30 07:53:55                     4.109589
23  2017-07-17 02:42:43                    20.000000
24  2017-06-30 07:38:00                     5.254237
25  2017-06-30 07:49:00                     4.920635
26  2017-06-30 05:26:26                     4.189189
```

EDIT:

For next data procesing if need `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['rent_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['rent_time'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['rent_time']).set_index('rent_time')
print (df)
                    rent_price_per_square_meter
rent_time                                       
2016-11-28 09:01:58                     0.400000
2016-11-28 09:02:35                     0.400000
2016-11-28 09:02:43                     0.400000
2016-11-28 09:03:21                     0.400000
2016-11-28 09:03:21                     0.400000
2016-11-28 09:03:34                     0.400000
2016-11-28 09:03:34                     0.400000
2017-06-17 02:49:33                     0.933333
2017-03-19 01:30:03                     0.490196
2017-03-10 06:39:03                    11.111111
2017-03-09 14:40:03                    16.666667
2017-06-08 03:27:52                    22.000000
2017-06-30 03:03:11                    22.000000
2017-02-20 11:04:48                    12.000000
2017-03-05 13:53:39                     6.842105
2017-03-06 14:00:01                     6.842105
2017-03-15 02:38:54                    20.000000
2017-03-15 02:19:07                    13.043478
2017-02-24 15:10:00                    25.000000
2017-06-26 02:17:31                    13.043478
2017-06-30 07:53:55                     4.109589
2017-07-17 02:42:43                    20.000000
2017-06-30 07:38:00                     5.254237
2017-06-30 07:49:00                     4.920635
2017-06-30 05:26:26                     4.189189
```

Comment: Hello, but I have another problem.when I want to group it and make a plot. An error occurs.TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Comment: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Comment: Check last edit, better solution for next data process.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: InnerDistrict_price_per_m2 = InnerDistrict_price_per_m2[InnerDistrict_price_per_m2['rent_time'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.datetime))]                                                              InnerDistrict_price_per_m2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).mean().plot()                                         TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151342/discussion-between-chunk-ning-and-jezrael).